# MySQL showing duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `people` and `comment`.

```
Table: people
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+------+
| id |      cn      |       en       |     dob     | role |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+------+
| 1  |  ChineseName |   EnglishName  |  1989-03-02 |   0  |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+------+
| 2  | ChineseName2 |   EnglishName2 |  1923-06-12 |   1  |
+-------------------+----------------+-------------+------+

Table: comment
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id |  owner | owner_id | creator_person_id |       comment       |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | PERSON |     2    |          1        |  Some comments here |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 2  | TRANSAC|     1    |          1        |       Comments      |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | PERSON |     1    |          1        |     Comments here   |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

When I execute the query:

```
SELECT comments.comment, 
creator_person.id AS creator_id,
creator_person.cn AS creator_cn,
creator_person.en AS creator_en,
creator_person.dob AS creator_dob,
creator_person.role AS creator_role
FROM people, comments
JOIN people AS creator_person
ON comments.creator_person_id = creator_person.id AND comments.owner = 'PERSON' AND comments.owner_id = 1
ORDER BY people.id
```

I suppose it will return me only 1 row, however I'm getting a duplicate of that row:

```
+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|      comment     | creator_id | creator_cn  | creator_en  | creator_dob | creator_role |
+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|   Comments here  |      1     | ChineseName | EnglishName |  1989-03-02 |       0      |
+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|   Comments here  |      1     | ChineseName | EnglishName |  1989-03-02 |       0      |
+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you joining `people` table twice. So you can modify your query to become:

```
SELECT comments.comment, 
creator_person.id AS creator_id,
creator_person.cn AS creator_cn,
creator_person.en AS creator_en,
creator_person.dob AS creator_dob,
creator_person.role AS creator_role
FROM comments
INNER JOIN people AS creator_person
ON comments.creator_person_id = creator_person.id 
   AND comments.owner = 'PERSON' AND comments.owner_id = 1
ORDER BY creator_person.id
```

also add `distinct` keyword if same problem occur like:

```
SELECT distinct comments.comment, ...
...
...
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, however it gave me error on `#1054 - Unknown column 'people.id' in 'order clause'` How should i fix this?

Comment: than change it to `ORDER BY creator_person.id`. Also I have modify the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
FROM people, comments
```

to:

```
FROM comments
```

Since you are joining on the `people` table you do not need to include it in the `FROM` clause.

You will also need to update your order clause to reflect the alias name you gave the people table:

```
ORDER BY creator_person.id
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, however it gave me error on `#1054 - Unknown column 'people.id' in 'order clause'` How should i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra join in there (an implicit one in `people,comments` since you are after doing an inner join with people you should remove the first).

```
select comments.comment,
  creator_person.id as creator_id,
  creator_person.cn as creator_cn,
  creator_person.en as creator_en,
  creator_person.dob as creator_dob,
  creator_person.role as creator_role
from comments
inner join people as creator_person
  on comments.creator_person_id = creator_person.id
where comments.owner = 'PERSON' and comments.owner_id = 1
order by creator_person.id;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8003/6)</kbd>

I also moved the other validations from the on clause to the where clause. In this case, you are doing a inner join, it wouldn't make a difference, but this is a bad habit and could make you do weird things when you use left/right joins in the future